# How to determine and solve mysql high CPU usage?

Tags: mysql

'top' gives:

```
top - 13:07:35 up 827 days,  8:18,  2 users,  load average: 5,26, 5,38, 5,45
KiB Mem:  32848512 total, 32265240 used,   583272 free,   261908 buffers
KiB Swap:  1046520 total,   313784 used,   732736 free, 28190744 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                  
23927 mysql     20   0  917m 243m 8152 S 553,7  0,8  65:09.27 mysqld





mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+------+--------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id   | User   | Host            | db          | Command | Time | State        | Info                                                               |
+------+--------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  600 | oneill | localhost       | NULL        | Query   |    0 | NULL         | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST                                              |
|  956 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:42219 | FoxPoker    | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 1318 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:44207 | FoxPoker    | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 1319 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:44210 | FoxPoker    | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 1321 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:44215 | FoxPoker    | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 1489 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:45218 | FoxPoker    | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 1490 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:45217 | FoxPoker    | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 1700 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:46246 | FoxPoker    | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 1701 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:46248 | FoxPoker    | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 2203 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:49218 | FoxPoker    | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 3262 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:54855 | FoxPoker    | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 3263 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:54858 | FoxPokerDev | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 3462 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:56029 | FoxPoker    | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 4269 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:60551 | FoxPoker    | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                               |
| 4945 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:36032 | FoxPoker    | Query   |    3 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(deviceId) FROM devices WHERE BINARY deviceId="pMGmpY" |
| 4950 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:36073 | FoxPoker    | Query   |    1 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(deviceId) FROM devices WHERE BINARY deviceId="tAf994" |
| 4952 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:36083 | FoxPoker    | Query   |    1 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(deviceId) FROM devices WHERE BINARY deviceId="ea6Kv2" |
| 4954 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:36097 | FoxPoker    | Query   |    1 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(deviceId) FROM devices WHERE BINARY deviceId="yFYvur" |
| 4955 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:36098 | FoxPoker    | Query   |    1 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(deviceId) FROM devices WHERE BINARY deviceId="73qTcv" |
| 4956 | oneill | 127.0.0.1:36099 | FoxPoker    | Query   |    1 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(deviceId) FROM devices WHERE BINARY deviceId="q64MfG" |
+------+--------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+



mysql> show status like '%onn%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| Aborted_connects         | 1     |
| Connections              | 5528  |
| Max_used_connections     | 25    |
| Ssl_client_connects      | 0     |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates | 0     |
| Ssl_finished_connects    | 0     |
| Threads_connected        | 19    |
+--------------------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(Connections keep on growing.)

```
mysqladmin status -h localhost -u  -p
Uptime: 924  Threads: 21  Questions: 92803  Slow queries: 1677  Opens: 1025  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 265  Queries per second avg: 100.436
```

I restared mysql, optimized all tables and nothing changed.

Any idea ?

Comment: in your code do you ever close a connection? or close a qry?

Comment: @yarek,  this looks like your application is not reusing the connection  or not closing the database connection. first look at the application how its connecting to the database.

Comment: Connections appears to be nothing more than a counter, if I'm reading the manual correctly. **"The number of connection attempts (successful or not)"** ... see this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections

Comment: If you have sysstat installed, can you [edit] in the output of the command `iostat`? This will show if your HDD is being a bottle neck / thrashing. Have you allocated enough memory to the process? Are you _swapping_? What about the output from `free` and `vmstat`?

Comment: The most important thing here is the slow query count. You seem to have a few of them. Look at the slow query log and post anything interesting

Comment: Thanks for running the show process list.  an you offer more information on the devices table and how deviceId is defined?  How large is the devices table?  Is there an index against deviceId?  Also, how long does it take you to run a query like SELECT COUNT(deviceId) FROM devices WHERE BINARY deviceId="yFYvur" and how frequently is this run?  I suspect this query is causing a table scan and locking any other iterations of this query (it seems to run often).  It would also be interesting to see the explain statement: Explain SELECT COUNT(deviceId) FROM devices WHERE BINARY deviceId="yFYvur";

Comment: Uptime of 827 days, so 2 years sine an update?

Answer (score 1):

Login to MySQL and check for expensive queries using:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

Find the offending sql that's causing the 1600 slow queries and performance tune it.

You can also look to enable slow query logging via the below documentation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html